# Python count capitals in string error when containing apostroph

Tags: python, string

Hi everybody I wrote the following code but I am getting an error whenever the input text contains an apostroph (`'`)

```
from collections import Counter
import string


def count_letters(word):
    BAD_LETTERS = "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z,  "
    return len([letter for letter in word if letter not in BAD_LETTERS])
    for letters in set(words):
            return count[letters]

word = "The Catcher in the Rye by J.D. Salinger TO MY MOTHER If you really want to hear about it, the first thing you’ll probably want to know is where I was born, an what my lousy childhood was like, and how my parents were occupied and all before they had me, and all that David Copperfield kind of crap, but I don’t feel like going into it, if you want to know the truth. In the first place, that stuff bores me, and in the second place, my parents would have about two hemorrhages apiece if I told anything pretty personal about them. They’re quite touchy about anything like that, especially my father. They’re nice and all, I’m not saying that, but they’re also touchy as hell. "
print count_letters(word)
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
% python /Users/shirin/Desktop/capitalsnew.py      [355]
  File "/Users/shirin/Desktop/capitalsnew.py", line 11
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/shirin/Desktop/capitalsnew.py on line 11, but no encoding declared
```

;

see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
Any ideas, thanks in advance!

Comment: What error you face with this code?

Comment: sorry copied the wrong code making corrections

Comment: Have you read http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/  as proposed?

Comment: you are returning a value before your for loop, so your for loop isn't executing.

Comment: I read it but i did not understand thats why I am asking here. I am new to python so i would appreciate if somebody could show me how to fix it on my code

Comment: What are you trying to do here?
And do you know yet how `return` statements work?

Comment: Well, it tells that you should write `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the beginning of your file.

Comment: Lol4t0 it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

`’` this character is not defined in ASCII, instead of `’` use this character `'`

I replaced the characters and there is no error:

```
word = "The Catcher in the Rye by J.D. Salinger TO MY MOTHER If you really want to hear about it, the first thing you'll probably want to know is where I was born, an what my lousy childhood was like, and how my parents were occupied and all before they had me, and all that David Copperfield kind of crap, but I dont feel like going into it, if you want to know the truth. In the first place, that stuff bores me, and in the second place, my parents would have about two hemorrhages apiece if I told anything pretty personal about them. They're quite touchy about anything like that, especially my father. They're nice and all, I'm not saying that, but they're also touchy as hell. "
```

**Option 2:**

Change Python Source Code Encoding: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Examples:

```
      #!/usr/bin/python
      # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
      import os, sys
      ...

      #!/usr/bin/python
      # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
      import os, sys
      ...

      #!/usr/bin/python
      # -*- coding: ascii -*-
      import os, sys
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the file encoding to be able to use non-ASCII characters like '’'. I think latin-1 is the recommended encoding for python 2 so put this at the very beginning of the file (but after the shebang if you have one):

`# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-`